# Default flag in Jquery Jgd dropdown select is incorrect

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, flags

I am having troubles with Jgd dropdown. I want to use the dropdown menu with flags to select the site language. (example 4. on the following link) - http://www.dev4press.com/jgd/dropdown/

```
 <select id="example-04">
    <option value="BR">Brasil</option>
    <option value="FR">France</option>
    <option value="DE">Germany</option>
    <option value="IN">India</option>
    <option value="JP">Japan</option>
    <option value="RS">Serbia</option>
    <option value="UK">United Kingdom</option>
    <option value="US">United States</option>
</select>
```

In example 4. is selected UK with UK flag. When I edit the javascript in the bottom of the page to JP, it changes the selected value to JP but not the flag. Flag remains UK.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    SyntaxHighlighter.defaults['toolbar'] = false;
    SyntaxHighlighter.all();
    $("select#example-04").jgdDropdown({
        clsLIPrefix: 'flag ', 
        cls: 'jgd-dropdown jgd-countries', 
        selected: 'JP'
    });
</script>
```

Comment: There is missing condition in file jquery.jgd.dropdown.js

     if (settings.clsCopySelect) {
          if ($(this).val() == selected.val()) {
                    $("#" + id + " dt").attr("class", cls);
             }
       }

Adding if ($(this).val() == selected.val()) { } condition causes that only selected value in dropdown reuses the css rules